# Shared local storage to use in my android application

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I am a beginner in android application. I want to create an android application, but instead of using a separate database (sqlite, firebase). I want to use my local storage (mobile storage) space itself.

For instance, There are 100 of members using my application. If one of the person want to share some document to others. Instead of sending the document, i want to share only the location to them (along with view or view/download option).
I am trying to achieve the security of the particular share documents. So that i believe it wont go outside my network members who are all using my application.
Each person can act as a server/client. Kind of mesh network topology.

Do we have any option already implemented in any other application.
Kindly help me.

Comment: Using sqlite based room or realm "locally" would help. You can use them locally

Comment: `i want to share only the location to them ` So for instance you would only tell name of the file or so?

Comment: yes I will share only my location of my file which is available in my mobile. More importantly i dont want to share my files out of my group.

Comment: Actually it's a kind of mesh network topology

Comment: And you are in New York and your friend is in Texas and then it should work?

Comment: yeah it's a kind of. . in nutshell, i want to implement a WAN file sharing only within a closed group of people.